# How does the isInArrears affect the quantlib IborLeg?

Tags: programming, bond, finance, quantlib, floating-rate

#### Deal details

```python
issue_date = ql.Date(31, 1, 2011)
maturity_date = ql.Date(31, 1, 2016)
coupon_rate = 6.23/100 
face_value = 250000
calendar = ql.NullCalendar() 
calendar.addHoliday(ql.Date(31,7,2011))
calendar.addHoliday(ql.Date(30,7,2011))
day_count = ql.Actual365Fixed()
payment_frequency = ql.Semiannual
schedule = ql.Schedule(issue_date,maturity_date,ql.Period(payment_frequency),calendar,ql.ModifiedFollowing,ql.ModifiedFollowing,ql.DateGeneration.Forward,False)
forcast_curve = ql.RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle()
curve = ql.FlatForward(0,ql.NullCalendar(),coupon_rate,ql.Actual365Fixed(),ql.Continuous)
forcast_curve.linkTo(curve)
index = ql.IborIndex("myindex",ql.Period(ql.Semiannual),0, ql.INRCurrency(),ql.NullCalendar(),ql.ModifiedFollowing,False,day_count,forcast_curve) 
index.clearFixings()                  
adates = [a for a in schedule]
arates = [0.055,0.0623,0.0623,0.0623,0.0623,0.0623,0.0623,0.0623,0.0623,0.0623,0.0623]
index.addFixings(adates, arates, True) 
iborleg = ql.IborLeg([face_value],schedule,index,day_count,ql.ModifiedFollowing,isInArrears=True)

#Coupon pricer
pricer = ql.BlackIborCouponPricer()

volatility = 1.0

vol = ql.ConstantOptionletVolatility(0,
                                     calendar,
                                      ql.ModifiedFollowing,
                                      volatility,
                                      ql.Actual365Fixed())

pricer.setCapletVolatility(ql.OptionletVolatilityStructureHandle(vol))

ql.setCouponPricer(iborleg, pricer)
cashflows = pd.DataFrame([(a.accrualStartDate(),a.accrualEndDate(),a.date(),a.amount(),a.accrualDays(),a.rate())
                    for a in [ql.as_coupon(c) for c in iborleg]],index=['']*len(iborleg))
cashflows.columns =["Start_Date","End_Date","Payment_Date","Amount","No_of_Days","Rate"]
cashflows
```

#### Output

```
Start_Date   End_Date Payment_Date  Amount      Days Rate
31/01/2011  29/07/2011  29/07/2011  7638.150685 179 0.0623
29/07/2011  31/01/2012  31/01/2012  7936.849315 186 0.0623
31/01/2012  31/07/2012  31/07/2012  7766.164384 182 0.0623
31/07/2012  31/01/2013  31/01/2013  7851.506849 184 0.0623
31/01/2013  31/07/2013  31/07/2013  7723.493151 181 0.0623
31/07/2013  31/01/2014  31/01/2014  7851.506849 184 0.0623
31/01/2014  31/07/2014  31/07/2014  7723.493151 181 0.0623
31/07/2014  31/01/2015  31/01/2015  7851.506849 184 0.0623
31/01/2015  31/07/2015  31/07/2015  7723.493151 181 0.0623
31/07/2015  31/01/2016  31/01/2016  7851.506849 184 0.0623
```

How does isInArrears affect the cashflows and its dates?
If I have 2 days isInarreas, how will it affect?

Answer (score 1):

In QuantLib the following occurs for the floating coupon if isInArrears is true:

```
Date FloatingRateCoupon::fixingDate() const {
    // if isInArrears_ fix at the end of period
    Date refDate = isInArrears_ ? accrualEndDate_ : accrualStartDate_;
    return index_->fixingCalendar().advance(refDate,
            -static_cast<Integer>(fixingDays_), Days, Preceding);
    }
```

i.e. the fixing is picked at the end of the accrual date or if false it is set at the start of the accrual period. This can be also observed in your code, if isInArrears is true then cashflows yield:

|  | Start_Date | End_Date | Payment_Date | Amount | No_of_Days | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2011-01-31 | 2011-07-29 | 2011-07-29 | 7638.150685 | 179 | **0.0623** |
| 1 | 2011-07-29 | 2012-01-31 | 2012-01-31 | 7936.849315 | 186 | 0.0623 |
| 2 | 2012-01-31 | 2012-07-31 | 2012-07-31 | 7766.164384 | 182 | 0.0623 |
| 3 | 2012-07-31 | 2013-01-31 | 2013-01-31 | 7851.506849 | 184 | 0.0623 |
| 4 | 2013-01-31 | 2013-07-31 | 2013-07-31 | 7723.493151 | 181 | 0.0623 |
| 5 | 2013-07-31 | 2014-01-31 | 2014-01-31 | 7851.506849 | 184 | 0.0623 |
| 6 | 2014-01-31 | 2014-07-31 | 2014-07-31 | 7723.493151 | 181 | 0.0623 |
| 7 | 2014-07-31 | 2015-01-31 | 2015-01-31 | 7851.506849 | 184 | 0.0623 |
| 8 | 2015-01-31 | 2015-07-31 | 2015-07-31 | 7723.493151 | 181 | 0.0623 |
| 9 | 2015-07-31 | 2016-01-31 | 2016-01-31 | 7851.506849 | 184 | 0.0623 |

and if set false:

|  | Start_Date | End_Date | Payment_Date | Amount | No_of_Days | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2011-01-31 | 2011-07-29 | 2011-07-29 | 6743.150685 | 179 | **0.055** |
| 1 | 2011-07-29 | 2012-01-31 | 2012-01-31 | 7936.849315 | 186 | 0.0623 |
| 2 | 2012-01-31 | 2012-07-31 | 2012-07-31 | 7766.164384 | 182 | 0.0623 |
| 3 | 2012-07-31 | 2013-01-31 | 2013-01-31 | 7851.506849 | 184 | 0.0623 |
| 4 | 2013-01-31 | 2013-07-31 | 2013-07-31 | 7723.493151 | 181 | 0.0623 |
| 5 | 2013-07-31 | 2014-01-31 | 2014-01-31 | 7851.506849 | 184 | 0.0623 |
| 6 | 2014-01-31 | 2014-07-31 | 2014-07-31 | 7723.493151 | 181 | 0.0623 |
| 7 | 2014-07-31 | 2015-01-31 | 2015-01-31 | 7851.506849 | 184 | 0.0623 |
| 8 | 2015-01-31 | 2015-07-31 | 2015-07-31 | 7723.493151 | 181 | 0.0623 |
| 9 | 2015-07-31 | 2016-01-31 | 2016-01-31 | 7851.506849 | 184 | 0.0623 |